# Not using a while(true) loop

Tags: java, loops

I recently asked a question over on code review, where I asked for someone to help optimise my code. I was told over there that using a `while (true)` was not useful, and I shouldn't do it. I then came over to look it through and I founf this exact question, about when to use one, and then answer said, you usually see one in games.

My question is when should I use one? And if I shouldn't use it now, what should I use instead?

Comment: It looks to me like the question has already been answered at code review. (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135610/making-a-game-called-hack-exe)

Comment: The specific objection is to loops that "busy wait". Busy wait loops are loops that do nothing except check a condition repeatedly. This could be phrased as `while(true) if (condition) break;`, as you did in your code, but equally could be written as `while(!condition);` (note the semicolon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you need to make a decision to exit the loop in the middle of loop's body. Java offers loop control in two places - at the beginning of each iteration (`while` and `for`) and at the end of each iteration (`do-while`). You use `while (true)` with a `break` in these situations:

```
while (true) {
    ... // Do something
    if (exitCondition) {
        break;
    }
    ... // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Or a `while(true)` with a `return` or `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)` +1